# Python 3.6 Flask with mod_wsgi on Windows : No module named queue

Tags: python, flask, mod-wsgi

I was playing around with a Flask/Python RESTful api and all was well until I started trying to learn how to serve it. Of course I tried this out locally.

I installed AMPPS since it comes with python and mod_wsgi installed and enabled by default. I went through all of the setups and I was able to get the default "Hello World!" application to work. Huzzah! Right?

Then I tried to start bringing in my app and this is where I've hit the road blocks.

At first, I was getting an error that there was no module named flask. After some reading I learned that I need to load my virtualenv like so:

```
activate_this = 'path/to/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

This seemed to work with flask, but then I got:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queue'`

I've scoured the interwebs and have read about "queue" vs "Queue" but I'm not importing it directly.

Here is the code that I have currently.

```
activate_this = 'path/to/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

# this line is what causes the error
from flask import Flask

def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = b'Hello World!'
    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]
    start_response(status, response_headers)
    return [output]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mod_wsgi is actually compiled for Python 2.7, not 3.6. The error is because the `Queue` module got renamed to `queue` in 3.6, so when import `queue` under 2.7 it will fail.

You will need to uninstall mod_wsgi and install a version of if that is compiled for Python 3.6. You cannot force a version of mod_wsgi compiled for one Python version to run as a different version by pointing it at a Python virtual environment of a different version. This is because mod_wsgi is linked direct to the Python library of a specific version.

Comment: Is this something that is easily done? I've never done that before. I'm a newbie to python.

Comment: Also, it seems odd that AMPPS would come with python 3, and have the 2.7 version of mod_wsgi.

Comment: Consider starting out by running the WSGI server on the command line using mod_wsgi-express. That way you don't need to touch the system Apache configuration. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mod_wsgi and http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/04/introducing-modwsgi-express.html

Comment: Does `pip install mod_wsgi-httpd` not work on Windows via a bash shell? I'm getting an error `'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.` I tried doing just `pip install mod_wsgi` but that seems to require Apache. Which isn't an issue really, I was just hoping to not have to since I'm usually running it in something like xampp.

Comment: You cannot use ``mod_wsgi-httpd`` on Windows. Only works on Linux, MacOS X and other UNIX like operating systems. It is recommended you use ApacheLounge distribution of Apache on Windows. I don't know if xampp provides the header files and libraries necessary to allow third party Apache modules to be compiled.

Comment: Yeah - I did end up installing Apache from ApacheLounge. The trouble is now `pip install mod_wsgi` errors stating that Microsot Visual C++ 14.0 is required. I already had 14.10 installed as well as a few others. Regardless, per the documentation on ApacheLounge, I downloaded it (v14.11) but I'm still getting the same error. :/ 

Thanks for the help thus far :)

Comment: Try from a CMD or PowerShell and run the ``bat`` file the compiler provides for setting the environment variables that are needed for the compiler to work.

Comment: Alright so I learned that even though I had them, they weren't necessarily "installed" or activated. So I activated them. Now, I'm getting a new error: `build\lib.win32-3.6\mod_wsgi\server\mod_wsgi.cp36-win32.pyd : fatal error LNK1120: 101 unresolved externals`. Before that is the 101 unresolved external symbol errors.Earlier in the log is a warning `c4005: 'PLATFORM' : macro redefinition` followed by 20ish c4244 warnings and possible loss of data.

I'm feeling kind of dumb here. The instructions seemed pretty straight forward, but I'm clearly missing something critical.

Comment: Ok, after some searching, I found that someone else had the same issue and they ended up having the 32 bit version of python installed. Turns out that I _also_ had the 32 bit version of python installed.

mod-wsgi-4.5.18 successfully installed. Thanks Graham.

If you want to add something to the tune of "make sure you're running the same platform of apache and python" to your answer I'll mark it as accepted.