# Python exe crashes when running

Tags: python, exe, cx-freeze

I'm running a Python executable file on my PC. I created it using `cx_freeze`. I ran it and I am getting the following errors:

```
 H:\>cmd /K C:\Executables\Minneapolis\build\exe.win-amd64-3.7\MinneapolisDiscovery.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\Python37\lib\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 40, in run
module.run()
File "C:\Python37\lib\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 23, in run
exec(code, {'__name__': '__main__'})
File "MinneapolisDiscovery.py", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python37\lib\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
import urllib3
File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 28, in <module>
from .packages.six.moves import queue
File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 92, in __get__
result = self._resolve()
File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 115, in _resolve
return _import_module(self.mod)
File "C:\Python37\lib\urllib3\packages\six.py", line 82, in _import_module
__import__(name)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'queue'
```

It looks like something related to `urllib3` or `requests`, but I've never gotten this error before. Any ideas on what I need to do to get this exe file to run?

Comment: Firstly, extract a [mcve]. If you have a Python program that is wrapped inside an executable, you will have to reduce that program first and include it along with the build commands you used. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3.6 Flask with mod\_wsgi on Windows : No module named queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46436834/python-3-6-flask-with-mod-wsgi-on-windows-no-module-named-queue)